I want to add components from my org to an installed unmanaged package in my org. Is it possible?
I have installed an unmanaged package in my org. Now I want to add an LWC Component in this org to the unmanaged package. Is it possible? If possible how to do that?

You can add a component that builds on components in the unmanaged package, but you cannot directly add the component to the unmanaged package itself. You would have to add the component to the unmanaged package in the packaging org, upload the new package version, uninstall the unmanaged package in the installation org, then install the new package version. In the future, consider using Unlocked Packages. Unlike Unmanaged Packages, Unlocked Packages can be upgraded without uninstalling previous versions.

But the requirement is adding a component in target org to the installed package.

That requirement is not possible, as explained in this answer.
